# disabled un input por cantidad de cambios

Tags: angular

soy nuevo en angular y mi proyecto requiere deshabilitar un campo si es que fue cambiado una cantidad de veces (3), pero no he dado con la logica para realizar el disabled, si alguien me puede orientar para llegar a una solucion lo agradeceria muchisimo...

---

pd. mi version de angular es 1.9.2

Comment: Hola Felipe. Aclarando, es `angularjs`? No es lo mismo que `angular`. Para cambiar la etiqueta. Y, que has echo hasta ahora? Puedes crear una variable `contador` y cada vez que haya un cambio en haces `contador++', pero sin código es difícil saber lo que necesitas.

Comment: Quisas esto te pueda ayuda[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42179150/how-to-disable-a-input-in-angular2/43765804)

Comment: Hola Felipe - Para que tengas mas oportunidad de que tu pregunta sea respondida, te recomiendo agregar el código dentro la pregunta. Puedes usar esta guía como referencia https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask